# Mass-renaming files remove some of them

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, standard-library

When renaming many files with `os.rename(src, dest)`, some of my files disappear.

I am on Ubuntu.

```
In [66]: len(os.listdir())                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[66]: 1430

In [67]: for i, name in enumerate(os.listdir()): 
    ...:     extension = os.path.splitext(name)[1] 
    ...:     dest = f"{i+1}{extension}" 
    ...:     os.rename(name, dest) 
    ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                           

In [68]: len(os.listdir())                                                                                                                                                                                         
Out[68]: 839
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the FineManual(TM)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rename) (emphasis is mine):

> **os.rename(src, dst, *, src_dir_fd=None, dst_dir_fd=None)**
>
> Rename the file or directory src to dst. If dst is a directory, OSError will be raised. **On Unix, if dst exists and is a file, it will be replaced silently if the user has permission**

So obviously, if you already have files matching `f"{i+1}{extension}"` they will get overwritten.

Comment: Thank you so much! I totally missed that in the doc.